# Code Contracts Checker - Can't resolve referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I'm trying to run code contract checking for a project that references external assemblies, but the contract checker fails to resolve the reference.

It gives the following error when building:

```
CodeContracts: Cannot load assembly '<Assembly to check>'
...
warning : CodeContracts: Assembly load resulted in metadata import error 'Assembly reference not resolved: <referenced assembly>.'
```

The cccheck command has the following arguments

```
-libPaths <string-arg>          : Search paths for reference assemblies
-resolvedPaths <string-arg>     : Candidate paths to dlls/exes for resolving references
```

I've tried setting both as "Extra Static Check Options" in project settings but am getting the same error.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Premium 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Comment: It would also be good to know the command line that is being passed to the rewriter, which you should be able to in the Output window of Visual Studio. Also, which version of Code Contracts?

Comment: Check the accepted answer to this question [Create code contracts for a legacy library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998720/create-code-contracts-for-a-legacy-library) as it would seem to solve the same problem.